# JSON data to Array

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my Javascript function that gets data from the HTML form.

```
$(function postProduct() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
      var productName = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var productDetail = document.getElementById("detail").value;
      var productCategory = document.getElementById("category").value;

      var dimensions = [productName, productDetail, productCategory];
      var keys = $.map(dimensions, function(value, key) {
        return value;
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/product/addproduct",
        data: keys,
        success: function(result) {
          alert('successful : ' + result);
          return result;
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("Not Working..");
        }
      });
    }

  });
});
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/product/addproduct")]
public IActionResult AddProduct([FromBody] string[] addproduct)
{
  var pProductName= addproduct[0];
  var pProductDetail= addproduct[1];
  var pProductCategory= addproduct[2];

  Hotel NewProduct = new Product();
  {
      NewProduct.ProductName= pProductName;
      NewProduct.ProductDetail= pProductDetail;
      NewProduct.ProductCategory= pProductCategory;
  }

  _db.Products.Add(NewProduct);
  _db.SaveChanges();

  //create a new route for post method by id
  return CreatedAtRoute(new { id = addproduct}, addproduct);
}
```

So, I'm trying to pass the inputted form and pass it to the controller by AJAX, However, it just fails.

This is the function that I use to make the json data to an array:

```
var dimensions = [productName, productDetail, productCategory];
var keys = $.map(dimensions, function(value, key) {
  return value;
});
```

Or should I recode my controller for accepting json data. If so, please give me an example on doing it. Sorry, I'm new at web api.

**UPDATE:**
This is my jsondata:

```
productName: name
productDeatil: detail
productCategory:category
```

This is my Array:

```
keys:(7) ["name", "detail", "category"]
```

Comment: How about an example of your JSON?

Comment: Not familiar at all with Asp.net Core, but it might be that you are not getting the data as JSON in your controller (you send as JSON, but you read it from the body in the wrong way. Check this out maybe? https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `data: JSON.stringifly(keys)` in ajax solve the problem. Thank you for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Is the spacing between NewProduct and properties such as .ProductName intentional?

```
NewProduct .ProductName = pProductName;
```

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
Hotel NewProduct = new Product();
NewProduct.ProductName = pProductName;
NewProduct.ProductDetail = pProductDetail;
NewProduct.ProductCategory = pProductCategory;
```

**With simplified object creation:**

```
Hotel NewProduct = new Product() {
    ProductName= pProductName,
    ProductDetail= pProductDetail,
    ProductCategory= pProductCategory
};
```

Comment: No, it just occurs when I copy and paste. Sorry about that.

Comment: I changed that code a bit as well... try removing the curly braces around where you're setting properties for NewProduct.  
It looks like you're already created the New Product instance.  When setting properties, the code does not need to be wrapped in curly braces.

Comment: If I do it without curly braces, it will show me a message (Object initialization can be simplified)

Comment: Isee maybe because you have that semi colon right after new Product();    I changed the code to include parenthesis,  under simplified object creation.

Comment: Thanks it did solve the message. However, I still couldn't pass the data to the controller. It did send a request, however, the value is null.

Comment: Do you mind posting more code?  your html,  the button that you're clicking the form.  Also.. how is postProduct() invoked?

Comment: I got it. Thanks btw. I just have to add JSON.stringify(keys) in my ajax.

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax request, assign the data key to the following value...

```
{ productName: document.getElementById("name").value, productDetail:  document.getElementById("detail").value, productCategory: document.getElementById("category").value }
```

This is a typical JSON formatted object.

You could then also remove your variable assignments and map function.

Finally you'd need to look into how to process this formatted JSON in your controller.

I'm unsure of how to go about this in asp.net-core-mvc but it could be something as simple as changing

`var pProductName= addproduct[0];`

to

`var pProductName= addproduct.productName`